# Modifying a Contact in AddressBook

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a contact service to add/modify/delete contacts and I'm stuck on how to modify a contact. This is the Contact class that I'm starting with:

```
public class Contact {

private String contactId;
private String firstName;
private String phone;

public Contact (String contactId, String firstName, String phone) {
    if (contactId == null || contactId.length() > 10) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid contact ID");
    }
    if (firstName == null || firstName.length() > 10) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid first name");
    }
    if (phone == null || phone.length() != 10) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid phone number");
    }
    
    this.contactId = contactId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getContactId() {
    return contactId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
}
```

In my contact service class, I have written the methods for creating and getting a contact

```
public class ContactService {

int Id = 000;

//create contactList array
private ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

public Contact getContact(String ID) {
    
    //iterates through contact list
    Iterator<Contact> itr = contactList.iterator();
    
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Contact contact = itr.next();
        if (contact.getContactId().equals(ID)) {
            
            //returns contact object for matching ID
            return contact; 
        } 
    }
    return null;
    }

//adds a contact to the contactList array
public Contact addContact(String firstName, String Phone) {

    Id++; //increment ID to make a unique ID
    
     //convert integer to string for ArrayList
    String contactId = Integer.toString(Id);
    //create contact object
    Contact contact = new Contact(contactId, firstName, Phone);
    //add contact to list
    contactList.add(contact);
    
    return contact;
    
}
```

For my `updateContact()` method, I want to call `getContact()` which should return a contact object but I'm not sure how to update the object from there. This is probably this closest I've come:

```
public void updateContact(String contactId, String firstName, String phone) {
    
    getContact(contactId);
            
    contact.setFirstName(firstName);
    contact.setPhone(phone);
    
}
```

However, not only does this approach not work but it would require me to create setter methods. If I do that the new input does not go through the null and length checks contained in the Contact constructor.

Comment: would calling the setter methods in your constructor and making whatever checks you want  in the setter methods work? Or Another way could be to make the contacts immutable and just create a new contact everytime the contact is  updated, however this could an expensive task if contacts are updated frequently.

Comment: Add checks in setters methods and use the setters in your constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update method does not work because you are calling getContact without storing return value of the method

```
public void updateContact(String contactId, String firstName, String phone) {
    Contact contact = getContact(contactId);
    contact.setFirstName(firstName);
    contact.setPhone(phone);
}
```

For make sure your checks are called you can call setter methods in your constructor like this

```
public Contact(String contactId, String firstName, String phone) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setPhone(phone);
    setContactId(contactId);
}
```

And check your values into setter methods

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    if (firstName == null || firstName.length() > 10) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid first name");
    }
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    if (phone == null || phone.length() != 10) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid phone number");
    }
    this.phone = phone;
}

public void setContactId(String contactId) {
    if (contactId == null || contactId.length() > 10) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid contact ID");
    }
    this.contactId = contactId;
}
```

Furthermore, you can improve your performance using an HashMap instead of ArrayList, so that you don't need to iterate whole the list every time you need a contact.

```
private final Map<String, Contact> contactList = new HashMap<>();

public Contact getContact(String ID) {
    return contactList.get(ID);
}

//adds a contact to the contactList array
public Contact addContact(String firstName, String Phone) {
    Id++;
    String contactId = Integer.toString(Id);
    Contact contact = new Contact(contactId, firstName, Phone);
    return contactList.put(contactId, contact);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: `List.get` has [different time complexities](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-analysis-of-arraylist-and-linkedlist-i). `ArrayList`, for instance, is O(1), the same as `HashMap`. So at least compared to `ArrayList`, `HashMap` isn't faster, but can be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

As @Atryom noted, you can add the same null and length checks that you have in your constructor to your setter methods. There's no restriction specifying that your setters cannot have those checks.